# how do i write from one file to another from a given position

Tags: php

I have a file handle which has traversed a file to a certain point (based on some logic)

I need to now copy the rest of the file starting from the handle position to the end of another file.

How can I do this optimally as the given file is large.

The long way would be

```
while (($line = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== FALSE) {
  write $line to the new file one at a time;
}
```

Comment: Read it into a variable and then `file_put_contents()`, with the `FILE_APPEND`, flag into the new file - assuming it's not so massive it uses all available system memory?

Comment: `file_put_contents` with `FILE_APPEND` will do lots of unnecessary file handle opening and closing behind the scenes.  It would probably be better to manually open the output file once with `fopen` and use `fwrite` multiple times.

Comment: yes i did not want to use file_put_contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like [stream_copy_to_stream](http://docs.php.net/function.stream-copy-to-stream) would do just that.

edit: [sscce](http://sscce.org/):

```
<?php
$fpSrc = fopen('php://memory', 'rwb');
$fpTarget = fopen('php://memory', 'rwb');

fwrite($fpSrc, join('', range('a', 'z'))); // some dummy data for the source stream
fseek($fpSrc, 0, SEEK_SET); // rewind

/* <--- the relevant code */
// searching for "delimiter"
while(!feof($fpSrc)) {
    $c = fread($fpSrc, 1);
    if ('m'===$c) break;
}
// copy remaining data
stream_copy_to_stream($fpSrc, $fpTarget);
/* end of relevant code ---> */

// rewind & print contents of target stream
fseek($fpTarget, 0, SEEK_SET);
echo stream_get_contents($fpTarget);
```

prints `nopqrstuvwxyz`.